# Leer un JSON en javascript o JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

amigos, por favor necesito de su ayuda, ya tengo toda la tarde dandole y no me sale, intento leer este JSON (una variable llamada dataJSON que contiene lo siguiente)

```
{
"datos": [{
    "kingMovement": {
        "id": 1255526,
        "idBlockchain": null,
        "date": "2022-03-15T17:56:53.000+00:00",
        "amount": 0,
        "generatorUser": "gMCY0xyWixNY97MSgSB2g2hrMSP2",
        "action": "GAME"
    },
    "game": {
        "id": 1199338,
        "date": "2022-03-15T17:56:53.000+00:00",
        "opponentId": "CCislHJOATSrRJ9zSUSIbkPExC62",
        "movements": "movimientos",
        "win": false,
        "draw": false,
        "kingBalance": null,
        "type": "RANKED",
        "reason": "surrender",
        "pieces": "WHITE",
        "matchId": null
    }
}, {
    "kingMovement": {
        "id": 1256124,
        "idBlockchain": null,
        "date": "2022-03-15T18:28:08.000+00:00",
        "amount": 24,
        "generatorUser": "gMCY0xyWixNY97MSgSB2g2hrMSP2",
        "action": "GAME"
    },
    "game": {
        "id": 1199627,
        "date": "2022-03-15T18:28:08.000+00:00",
        "opponentId": "JJwfUDksI9T1QtF3dGfnSInkT1p1",
        "movements": "movimientos",
        "win": true,
        "draw": false,
        "kingBalance": null,
        "type": "RANKED",
        "reason": "checkmate",
        "pieces": "BLACK",
        "matchId": null
    }
}]
```

}

he intentando algo asi, pero nada (esto es un ejemplo)

```
var obj = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
    var Misdatos = obj.datos;
    
    for(i in Misdatos){  
        cad += "<br/>" + Misdatos[i].kingMovement;                                   
    };
```

y no  logro hacerlo, la verdad ya me tiene loco, he buscado, leido, implementado, pero no me sale
gracias por su ayuda

---

amigo, respondi asi para poder hacerlo bien, dataJSON contiene el texto que capture de un responseText

```
De esta manera, no me funiciona
alert(dataJSON.datos[0].kingMovement.id);
```

asi, tampoco

const json = dataJSON;

```
    alert(json.datos[0].kingMovement.id);
    alert(json.datos[0].game.opponentId);
```

y asi tampoco

```
    let json = dataJSON;
    alert(json.datos[0].kingMovement.id);
    alert(json.datos[0].game.opponentId);
```

yo coloco el JSON en https://jsonlint.com/ y me dice que esta OK, la verdad no se que sucede

Comment: Incluye todo lo que has intentado y todos los errores que has encontrado. También te sugiero que realices el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.

Comment: Si no te sale es porque tu `JSON` tiene un error, pon el error que te sale.

Comment: gracias amigo, yo coloco el JSON en https://jsonlint.com/ y me dice que esta OK, y lo increible es que coloco lo que me dieron en la otra respuesta (todo) y funciona, pero es que el JSON es exactamente ese mismo, pero yo lo capturo de un responseText y no se si esto tenga algo que ver, pero el texto es exactamente igual

Answer (score 1):

Amigo Simon, partimos de la base de que ya tienes declarada como objeto (JSON) la variable, por lo que no debes utilizar el método JSON.parse, que en realidad es para transformar una cadena (string) en objeto.
Te he puesto un ejemplo de lo que entiendo que querías, que es recorrer el array de "datos" para acceder a ciertos campos de cada uno de sus elementos, que como decía Hernán, a su vez son también objetos.

```js
let dataJSON = {
    "datos": [
          {
              "kingMovement": {
                  "id": 1255526,
                  "idBlockchain": null,
                  "date": "2022-03-15T17:56:53.000+00:00",
                  "amount": 0,
                  "generatorUser": "gMCY0xyWixNY97MSgSB2g2hrMSP2",
                  "action": "GAME"
              },
              "game": {
                  "id": 1199338,
                  "date": "2022-03-15T17:56:53.000+00:00",
                  "opponentId": "CCislHJOATSrRJ9zSUSIbkPExC62",
                  "movements": "movimientos",
                  "win": false,
                  "draw": false,
                  "kingBalance": null,
                  "type": "RANKED",
                  "reason": "surrender",
                  "pieces": "WHITE",
                  "matchId": null
              }
          }, {
              "kingMovement": {
                  "id": 1256124,
                  "idBlockchain": null,
                  "date": "2022-03-15T18:28:08.000+00:00",
                  "amount": 24,
                  "generatorUser": "gMCY0xyWixNY97MSgSB2g2hrMSP2",
                  "action": "GAME"
              },
              "game": {
                  "id": 1199627,
                  "date": "2022-03-15T18:28:08.000+00:00",
                  "opponentId": "JJwfUDksI9T1QtF3dGfnSInkT1p1",
                  "movements": "movimientos",
                  "win": true,
                  "draw": false,
                  "kingBalance": null,
                  "type": "RANKED",
                  "reason": "checkmate",
                  "pieces": "BLACK",
                  "matchId": null
              }
          }
    ]
    
}
    var arrDatos = dataJSON.datos,
            cad = "";
    
    arrDatos.forEach(function(datoActual) {
       cad += "<br/>kM id:" + datoActual.kingMovement.id + "--> amount:" + datoActual.kingMovement.amount + " || game id: " + datoActual.game.id;
    });    
    console.log(cad);
```

Puedes verlo también en https://jsfiddle.net/8u7w1zvj/

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu objeto se llame dataJSON podrias leer los datos asi:

```
let dataJSON= {
"datos": [{
    "kingMovement": {
        "id": 1255526,
        "idBlockchain": null,
        "date": "2022-03-15T17:56:53.000+00:00",
        "amount": 0,
        "generatorUser": "gMCY0xyWixNY97MSgSB2g2hrMSP2",
        "action": "GAME"
    },
    "game": {
        "id": 1199338,
        "date": "2022-03-15T17:56:53.000+00:00",
        "opponentId": "CCislHJOATSrRJ9zSUSIbkPExC62",
        "movements": "movimientos",
        "win": false,
        "draw": false,
        "kingBalance": null,
        "type": "RANKED",
        "reason": "surrender",
        "pieces": "WHITE",
        "matchId": null
    }
}, {
    "kingMovement": {
        "id": 1256124,
        "idBlockchain": null,
        "date": "2022-03-15T18:28:08.000+00:00",
        "amount": 24,
        "generatorUser": "gMCY0xyWixNY97MSgSB2g2hrMSP2",
        "action": "GAME"
    },
    "game": {
        "id": 1199627,
        "date": "2022-03-15T18:28:08.000+00:00",
        "opponentId": "JJwfUDksI9T1QtF3dGfnSInkT1p1",
        "movements": "movimientos",
        "win": true,
        "draw": false,
        "kingBalance": null,
        "type": "RANKED",
        "reason": "checkmate",
        "pieces": "BLACK",
        "matchId": null
    }
}]
}

console.log(dataJSON.datos[0].kingMovement.id);
console.log(dataJSON.datos[0].game.reason);
console.log(dataJSON.datos[1].kingMovement.id);
console.log(dataJSON.datos[1].game.reason);
```

La estructura de tu objeto es un array datos que a su vez contienen un objeto con dos propiedades (kingMovement y game) que a su vez contienen un objeto mas cada uno. En los console.log te indico la forma para llegar hasta el ultimo de los campos de cada objeto.

Podrias iterar con un map() para obtener los valores de cada elemento del array, por ejemplo para obtener todos los reason seria asi:

```
let reasons = dataJSON.datos.map(el => el.game.reason)

console.log(reasons)
```

tube que lidiar con esto una vez que exportaba los datos de una db de sql server a JSON y hasta que me di cuenta que los sacaba como array me volvi loco. Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias amigo, por favor ve el mensaje que deje, la verdad NO logro hacer que funcione, no entiendo, gracias

Comment: lo increible es que coloco lo que me pusiste en la respuesta y funciona, pero es que el JSON es exactamente ese mismo, pero yo lo capturo de un responseText y no se si esto tenga algo que ver, pero el texto es exactamente igual

Comment: no uses responseText usa response, ahi es donde viene la data en formato adecuado

Comment: Bueno, igual cambie a response solamente, y sigue igual, la verdad NO termino de entender porque no funciona, eso haciendo exactamente el mismo codigo que me pasaron en la primera respuesta, solo que el JSON lo obtengo del responseText y es exactamente el mismo texto, el resto lo hago igual y NO funciona, pero si creo el json en el mismo codigo, si lo lee jejejejejje, no se

Comment: ResponseText es formato texto. Porque no subes la peticion asi lo vemos

Comment: pudiera subirla, pero realmente es no es el problema digo yo, pues el ResponseText me trae la información tal cual la puse desde la pregunta, y yo hago un alert y efectivamente me muestra todo el texto, lo guardo para revisarlo y está ok, lo subo a la pagina jsonlint.com y me dice que está OK. El problema es que NO logro leer la información, y he realizado lo que me han explicado aqui y NO me funciona, pero si coloco el texto en el propio codigo, asignado a una variable, y lo leo, pues SI lo lee y me muestra lo que quiero; es una cuestion extraña

Comment: Listo amigos, muchas gracias, despues de tanto darle y darle, logre hacerlo, pero NO entiendo aún porque no salia, si es practicamente lo mismo que estoy intentando desde ayer, pero bueno, gracias a todos